# gif image loading until page completely loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, animated-gif

I have `gif` image and I want to load `gif` image which shows loading website until page completely loads.I try `gif` image not working well. `Gif` not animated till web site completely load.Can anyone help me?
Here is my code:

```
<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
      $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
    })
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
    .loader {
      background: url('image/loading.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(0, 0, 0);
      background-color: black;
      position: fixed;
      left: 0px;
      top: 0px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      z-index: 999999999999999999999999999999999999999;
      opacity: .7;
    }
  </style>
  <div class="loader">

    <body>
    </body>
```

And here is my website link [a link](http://www.wenggs.com/2017/index100.html)

Comment: Your link works good. It shows the loader in front, and the website loads in background. Is that what you want?

Comment: gif image not working well. Gif not animated till website completely load.`gif` image not loading in start again check and i also want black background when `gif` image loading.Currently it show website background.

Comment: That's not true at all. This entirely depends on your computer's network connection. I see the background and the loader first, having your site loaded behind.

Comment: `gif` image not show animation i mean moving circle not correctly.It start late first it stop some seconds then it animated.I want to animated correctly.

Comment: Your `.loader` div is outside the `body` tag. That's invalid HTML right there.

Comment: @asprin i also try after <body> tag in initial but same problem

Comment: @31piy i want this thing [link](http://dev.bradsknutson.com/demos/page-loader/)  but i want to replace my `gif` image .It working fine .Please visit link

Answer (score 0):

Try to show your loader before your window.load function like that :

```
 $(".loader").show();
 $(window).load(function() {
  $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
 });
```

This code should show your loader and when your website is load, the loader should fade out slowly.
If you to hide your website background during loading, put an overlay over your website : create a div with "overlay" class with a background and a high z-index, put your loader inside your div and that should work.

Comment: I want black background while `gif` image loading i want this thing [link] ( http://dev.bradsknutson.com/demos/page-loader/) but i want to replace my gif image .It working fine .Please visit link

Comment: same problem .Gif image not start in initial loading page

Comment: when page load then `gif` image start animated.But i don't want this .I want before page load it will display.Same like this [LINK](http://dev.bradsknutson.com/demos/page-loader/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate.

Add this code a very simple way to add loader on your web page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#preloader').fadeOut(5000,function(){$(this).remove();});
});
});
</script>
  <style type="text/css">
    .js div#preloader {position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; z-index:99999; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: visible; background:#fff url('images/loader.gif') no-repeat center center;background-size:60px 60px;}
  </style>
  <div class="loader">
    <div id="preloader"></div> <--USE-THIS-DIV-->
    <body>
    </body>
  </div>
</html>
```

Comment: I want that when page `tab` circle moving then `gif` image animated in center of page with black background and when `tab` circle stop moving its mean page fully loaded then `gif` image vanished .

Comment: Kindly use the above code will solve your problem. The gif image will revolve on the center of the page and when page will load fully the background will hide slowly.

Comment: sorry this is not working and now my `gif` image disappear

Comment: I dont't find the loader gif on this folder.. http://www.wenggs.com/2017/assets/images/ and change the image path to background:#fff url('/assets/images/loader.gif') no-repeat center center; and add th gif image with the name loader.gif will sure solve the problem.

Comment: hi..kindly check site [link](http://www.wenggs.com/2017/index100.html) not working well.loading image

Comment: There are many JS from Google library use only one I have checked used 5-6 times. JS id conflicting my dear..

Comment: can you help me on team viwer please?

Answer (score 0):

Check below code...

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        myVar = setTimeout(showPage, 3000);
    });
    function showPage() {
        document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";
    }
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .loader {
        background: url('loader.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(0, 0, 0);
        background-color: black;
        position: fixed;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 999999999999999999999999999999999999999;
        opacity: .7;
    }
</style>
<body id="myDiv" style="margin:0;">
    <div id="loader" class="loader">&nbsp;</div>
    Hello this is a testing...........
</body>
```

Comment: i use  your code .Kindly check website now [link](http://www.wenggs.com/2017/index100.html) not working properly